# How to change pythonPath in python-shell?

Tags: javascript, python, electron

I'm trying to write python app (for study project) using Electron (because I want to make my app look nice, so I am learning javascript, html and css too). I try to use python-shell to run python script from javascript. I installed python into the folder with my project and want to use interpreter for the project from this folder, but nodejs uses the interpreter from another folder Anaconda3 (which was installed several months before and is used for other projects). I try to change path to interpreter using options={pythonPath: 'relative path to python.exe'} in python-shell constructor in .js files, but that just doesn't change anything. What can I do to change path to interpreter that I need? Thank you.
My OS is Windows.

```
    var options = {
  mode: 'text',
  pythonPath: 'python'
  };
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell',options)
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked after I restarted my computer.